# Is it possible to search Gmail for messages sent after working hours?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

For instance, I'm looking for messages that arrived between 5PM and 10PM from a range of dates, February to August.

How can I easily search for them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send all incoming email to a folder while "Out of Office"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39763/send-all-incoming-email-to-a-folder-while-out-of-office)

Comment: This question does not appear to be a duplicate of the "Out of Office" question mentioned above. This question is about searching previously-received messages, not creating a rule for incoming messages.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Gmail's search doesn't include any filters for time; only dates. There may be a browser extension out there that will filter Gmail messages by time, but I haven't seen it. I don't know how familiar you are with coding, but you could possibly write your own, for the browser of your choice.  You'd need to take a look at how Google formats the time structure for emails, but it can probably be done.